# Why is my array declaration not working as expected?

Tags: go

Newbie to Go here. Why am I getting a compile time error when I declare an array this way ?

```golang
func CountPositivesSumNegatives(numbers []int) []int {
  
  // Compile Time Error : cannot use result (type [2]int) as type []int in return argument
  var result [2]int 
  
  for _,number := range numbers {
    
    if (number > 0) {
      result[0] += 1
    } else {
      result[1] += number
    }
    
  }
  
  
  return result
  
}
```

If I change the code to be this way, it works , but I am not sure why ?

```golang
func CountPositivesSumNegatives(numbers []int) []int {
  
  
  result := []int{0,0}
  
  
  for _,number := range numbers {
    
    if (number > 0) {
      result[0] += 1
    } else {
      result[1] += number
    }
    
  }

  return result
  
}
```

Comment: The statement `var result [2]int` declares an [array](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/6) variable.  The function is declared to return a [slice](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/7). A slice is not an array.  The statement `result := []int{0,0}` declares a slice variable.  See https://go.dev/play/p/sTQHvpzuVdz for other ways to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go compiler is telling you the exact error here:
"*Compile Time Error : cannot use result (type [2]int) as type []int in return argument*" - declared return type and type of returned value do not match.

Your function `CountPositiveSumNegatives()` return type is declared as `[]int` (slice of integers) but type of what you return is `[2]int` (2 element integer array).

To fix your first example you need to change return type to `[2]int`

```golang
func CountPositivesSumNegatives(numbers []int) [2]int {
```

Or as you found out you can make result an integer slice.

To read more about arrays and slices and difference between them I recommend this official Go Blog post called [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro)